# Synchronizing Gradle failed due to unknown issues with downloads

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, synchronization

I have been trying to fix this error all day now. All I did in the morning was update the compiler I had on my Android Studio. That's when everything went horribly wrong. Since then I have uninstalled the compiler...

These are the types of errors I keep getting everytime I try sync gradle:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
         https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom
         https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar
```

Is the latest and one I can't solve... things I've tried:

- To solve the other problems I physically downloaded the jar files and
  put them in the respective places (which failed with kotlin 1.2.0)...
- I also added this to my gradle:

.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

This fixed my other issues...

- I tried running from offline mode which failed...
- I tried downloading the files into the project and referencing it like this:

.

```
compile files('kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar')
```

I have long since removed the compiler just stuck as to what to do... I couldn't find any way online to fix my problem

Comment: Keep in mind `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` are minSdk 24.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem after updating to new Android Studio too. You need to provide the dependency with new Kotlin version explicitly. In your app level build.gradle file add:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.30"
```

Also you might need to add other dependencies:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.30"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.30"
```

Comment: Man I had this problem too... I just deleted everything and pulled from my repo after reinstalling

Comment: It didn't work... I'm going to just try do what @ThabisoMotswagole did and see if that works